# HTTP Service Request Queues\CurrentQueueSize counter instance name

Tags: iis, perfmon

I am currently looking to monitor the Current Queue Size counter and have been poking about in PowerShell via `Get-Counter -Counter "\HTTP Service Request Queues(*)\CurrentQueueSize"` which returns the values I am interested in.

The returned value are clearly organised by AppPool but I don't recognise one of them.

```
\\computername\http service request queues(defaultapppool)\currentqueuesize : 0
\\computername\http service request queues(---2)\currentqueuesize : 0
```

What is `---2` representing? I have run the command against other servers and they return similar results but a different number, I've seen a `---1`,`---42` and a few other different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test the command in my server and it also responses different value of http service.
[image]

So we cannot figure out what they mean but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/scenario-3--performance-counters) has explained this result.

> However, some server applications may have unnamed Request Queues that cannot be matched to a performance counter instance ID.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I looked at that page many many times and managed to completely miss that.